# Visualsearch.js - How to call search method?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to create Search button. What is the click function of the button?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for: onClick()
If not, provide more info.

Comment: when i init a VisualSearch object, i set the serch function such as
var visualSearch = VS.init({
      container : $('.visual_search'),
      query     : '',
      callbacks : {
        search       : function(query, searchCollection) {},....

Comment: ok, so reviewing code (http://documentcloud.github.com/visualsearch/docs/search_box.html) says it all : "Hitting enter or clicking the search button". In my case, this was not firing, even when clicking or enter, so it must be the event is getting intercepted and prevented from further propagation.